# JS: how generate the product array for Google Analytics dataLayer?

Tags: javascript, django, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Javascript wisdom needed.

I need a way of generating the product array for **Google Analytics** `dataLayer`, when using Django as Backend and sending `{{ order_items }}` variable to `thank_you_page.html` template:

```
products: [{
            id: 'product_id',
            name: 'Product A',
            price: '24.00',
            quantity: 1,
            coupon: 'FOR20'
          },{
            id: 'another_product_id',
            name: 'MY ADD-ON',
            price: '1.00',
            quantity: 1,
            coupon: 'ADD-ONS OFF'
          }]
```

> It is going to be part of a `dataLayer` that is going to use
>   afterwards to capture values for Google Analytics, via Google Tag
>   Manager.

I'm using Django for the backend and I'm sending this variables to the frontend:

```
{{order}}

{{order_items}}
```

And said before this array must be inside another "parent" array, according to this blog post from a [Google Analytics Expert](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enhanced-ecommerce-guide-for-google-tag-manager/):

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'eec.purchase',
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: 'EUR',
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: 'ORDER12345',
        affiliation: 'Simo\'s shop',
        revenue: '11.00',
        tax: '1.00',
        shipping: '2.00',
        coupon: 'SUMMER2019'
      },
      products: [{
            id: 'product_id',
            name: 'Product A',
            price: '24.00',
            quantity: 1,
            coupon: 'FOR20'
          },{
        id: 'another_product_id',
        name: 'MY ADD-ON',
        price: '1.00',
        quantity: 1,
        coupon: 'ADD-ONS OFF'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

**Should I put an empty `products = []`, and then do the for loop to push the elements inside?**

```
products = []
{% for item in order_items %}
   products.push({
     id: item.id,
     name: item.name,
     price: item.price,
     quantity: item.quantity,
     coupon: item.coupon
   });
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Using this code:

```
{% block data_layer %}
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'eec.purchase',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'PEN',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: {{ order_number }},
                        affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                        revenue: {{ total }},
                        shipping: {{ costo_despacho }},
                        coupon: 'SUMMER2019'
                    }
                },
                products: []
            }
        });
    </script>


    {% for item in order_items %}
        <script>
            window.dataLayer.ecommerce.products.push({
                id: item.order.id,
                name: item.name,
                price: item.price,
                quantity: item.quantity
            });
        </script>
    {% endfor %}



{% endblock %}
```

**Got error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined
>       at (index):72

***This is line 72:***

```
 window.dataLayer.ecommerce.products.push({
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question was about creating the product array (in Javascript) from a Python List (or Array in other languages).

The complexity of the question was because I (the owner of the question) didn't understand how to work with the python list **in the template** to generate a ***javascript array.***

The answer is that you need to send the `python list` to the template using a serializer:

```
def thanks_deposit_payment(request):
    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id

    total = Order.objects.latest('id').total

    costo_despacho = Order.objects.latest('id').shipping_cost

    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))


    order_items = serialize('json', order_items, fields=['id', 'sku', 'product', 'price', 'size', 'quantity'])

    response = render(request, 'thanks_deposit_payment.html', dict(order_number=order_number, total=total,
                                                                   order_items=order_items, costo_despacho=costo_despacho))
    return response
```

In `thanks_deposit_payment.html`, the template, you have to use JSON:

Like this: `products: JSON.parse('{{ order_items | safe }}')`

```
{% block data_layer %}

    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'eec.purchase',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'PEN',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: {{ order_number }},
                        affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                        revenue: {{ total }},
                        shipping: {{ costo_despacho }},
                        coupon: ''
                    },
                    products: JSON.parse('{{ order_items | safe }}')
                },

            }
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say, this is good practice. I assume, that order_items is an array of items.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'eec.purchase',
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: 'EUR',
    purchase: {
      actionField: {
        id: 'ORDER12345',
        affiliation: 'Simo\'s shop',
        revenue: '11.00',
        tax: '1.00',
        shipping: '2.00',
        coupon: 'SUMMER2019'
      }
    },
    products: []
  }
});
```

Then use forEach to push items into products.

```
 order_items.forEach(item => {
   window.dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products.push({
     id: item.id,
     name: item.name,
     price: item.price,
     quantity: item.quantity,
     coupon: item.coupon
   });
 });
```

Comment: I does not work. Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: order_items is not defined, I think it is because you access Django variables in html like: {{ order_items }}

Comment: I had to remove purchase in `window.dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products.push({` as product is not inside purchase and I was getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push data directly into a selected key of the dataLayer. You need to push data to dataLayer itself:

```
dataLayer.push({...});
```

For your specific case, it is also a better practice to place all the product data of the purchase call into one push, as you need to process it together, and this way GTM will not know, which was the last product, when the product array is considered ready.

So my suggestion is to loop the products, and place them as array of objects into products, as expected by enhanced ecommerce data:

```
{% block data_layer %}
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'eec.purchase',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'PEN',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: {{ order_number }},
                        affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                        revenue: {{ total }},
                        shipping: {{ costo_despacho }},
                        coupon: 'SUMMER2019'
                    }
                },
                products: [

    {% for item in order_items %}
                  {
                    id: item.order.id,
                    name: item.name,
                    price: item.price,
                    quantity: item.quantity
                  },
    {% endfor %}
                ]
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, please note, that this initialization is usually used before calling the GTM base code:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```

Whereas event is usually specified with a later data push, to let GTM act on this specific event:

```
event: 'eec.purchase'
```

Using event in the initial call might still work (haven't tested), but it can already be processed with the Page View event as well.